# librosa load the sound file change its shape and file size

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav, librosa

Let say I have sound file dog.wav  as 32.0kb

```
  y, sr = librosa.load(os.path.join(train_data_path, label, fname))
 librosa.output.write_wav('./input/train_test/'+label+'/AUG_'+fname,y,sr)
```

I did nothing except just loading file and re-write it to another folder. 
 but it change the file size as 72kb and shape

```
99,81,1 -> 71,81,1
```

is there way to keep the same file size and shape when I change the sound file with librosa?

Comment: You don't say what language this is in, which appears to be Python. Anyway, read the API for `write_wav()`. It looks like it resamples the data, which is almost never going to result in the same exact _file_ contents unless you know how it was sampled in the first place. And even then, I don't think the process is _necessarily_ symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

librosa `load` function resamples the input file at `sr=22050` by default,
which probably not the source sampling rate.

You can pass `sr=None` to the load function:

`_, sr = librosa.core.load("file",`**`sr=None`**`)`

https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html
https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/659